# Laravel Vue SPA. Can run app fine with "npm run dev", but "npm run production" hangs compiling with no errors

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, npm, webpack

I am building an SPA with Laravel and Vue.js.

After running 'npm run dev' the compiling freezes without completing and producing no errors.

When running 'npm run watch' the first compile freezes the same as above but after updating any file the compiler completes and the application works as expected.

The only difference I can see is on a successful dev compile I get: `+ XX hidden assets`, where as a failed one just stops with no response.

Any help or suggestions on what to try next appreciated.

Have already tried:

- increasing the server RAM and page file to 2GB;
- running npm locally (same results)
- updating node to the latest version;
- running `npm run production --verbose` no-errors same results.

App/System:

- Ubuntu 18 VPS;
- Laravel 5.8;
- npm 6.9.0;
- node 10.16.2

Example of hang after `npm run watch` or 'npm run dev':

```
...
dist/js/7.155d38.js   2.67 KiB       7  [emitted]         
dist/js/8.986615.js   2.67 KiB       8  [emitted]         
dist/js/9.8f4e2a.js   1.34 KiB       9  [emitted]
```

After updating a file forcing watch to run for the second time it will then complete and app will work fine:

```
...
dist/js/dbe9b016dac95985995f.js  1.41 MiB            22  [emitted]  
dist/js/ee7b33e8f1bd454e4b27.js  51.5 KiB            51  [emitted]  
dist/js/f2b5a0dec2e6bbb89bfc.js  56.2 KiB            53  [emitted]  
 + 24 hidden assets
```

This will happen no matter which file I update

Comment: So far I have found that they issue was related to the SCSS compiling but not sure what exactly. 

In the meantime I am compiling the SCSS locally and not through webpack then uploading the compiled css separately.

Comment: NPM can hang due to memory issues, at lot of the time this is at 99%, try allocating your machine more swap memory.